# wordCount job failed spring batch

Tags: maven, hadoop, spring-data, spring-batch, cloudera

I am a beginner learning about Hadoop and Spring integration. I was trying to run a wordcount program using **Cloudera ( cdh4.5.0 )** version and **Spring Batch 2.2.4** version using Maven.

The program compiles successfully and the map and reduce functions are completed. Still the wordcount job gives a status of Job failed and the following error:

```
ERROR [org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep] - <Encountered an error executing the step>
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter, but class was expected
```

I have seen the dependency tree and can not find any conflicting previous versions of hadoop in my repository. If you need any more information please let me know.

Any help or suggestion is most welcome :)

Thanks

Comment: Am I only facing this issue ? Is spring batch compatible with cdh4.5 ?

Comment: @bellabax: I agree that the issue is quite similar but there are no answers suitable for my question. Please look into this.

Comment: I have even changed the cloudera version to 4.3.1 but still no change in the error.

Comment: Just because the other question doesn't have the right answer, this is no reason to ask a duplicate. Either clarify (by editing the question) what exactly is different in your case, or accept that this question will be closed as duplicate.

Comment: I will take care of that in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using spring-data-hadoop as well.

Try using the 1.0.2.RELEASE-cdh4 version with Cloudera CDH4 - these distro specific releases are available in the Spring repository:

```
<repository>
  <id>spring-releases</id>
  <name>Spring Release Repository</name>
  <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
</repository>
```

More info here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop/wiki/Build-with-Cloudera-CDH4